# Sincronización de dos BBDD MySQL con PHP lógica

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A ver: tengo dos bases de datos en MYSQL y tengo que sincronizarlas con PHP. En concreto, es una sincronización con las siguientes características:

-Se actualizarán seis campos (IdPedido, cod_pedido_prov, agencia_prov, url_tracking, numeroseguimiento, Estado). 
-Las actualizaciones serán unidireccionales, es decir, siempre desde la tabla pedidos hacia la tabla pedidos_remoto. 
-Ambas tablas no coinciden en campos (la mayoría de campos son iguales, pero algunos son diferentes) ni en tamaño (pedidos_remoto puede tiene normalmente más datos que pedidos). 
-Se persigue que cuando alguien cambie alguno de los mencionados campos en la tabla pedidos que se actualice de forma automática en la tabla pedidos_remoto.

El problema que tengo es que no tengo ni idea de qué lógica usar para ello. Por ahora, la idea vaga que tengo es:

-Crear dos arrays donde meto los datos de esos campos de todos los registros. 
-Comparar ambos arrays y cuándo los datos no coincidan pues...hacer algo. El problema que claro, las BBDD no tienen la misma longitud (con lo cual ya le veo lagunas a esto) y, por otro lado, luego no sabría qué hacer con el dato sacado, ya que tendría un dato suelto que no sabría de dónde es.

No tengo ni idea de por dónde enfocar este problema. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: La respuesta es claramente basada en opiniones.. podrias probar en el [chat].. formas de hacer esto hay muchas y todas dependen de la infraestructura y como quieras atacar el problema. En mi opinion, atacarlo con arrays es la peor opcion de todas...

Comment: Esto parece un ejercicio de clase.

Comment: Lo he puesto así para que sea la información clara. Pero no, no es un ejercicio de clase, soy un estudiante en prácticas y es un problema real al que me enfrento. Respecto a lo de que es una respuesta claramente basada en opiniones... ¿no se pueden hacer preguntas sobre lógica de programación en Stack Overflow? Gracias.

Comment: Creo que el principal problema es **que las dos BD no son iguales**. Entonces cabe preguntar: ***¿por qué motivo hay que sincronizar dos BD de datos que no son iguales?*** En caso de que haya una razón justificada, cabe preguntar otra cosa: ***¿cuál es la política de manejo de los casos desiguales?*** Teniendo clara esa política, entonces podrás reflejarla en un código concreto. Los problemas se verbalizan primero (se explican de una forma teórica) y luego los puedes resolver en programación. Aquí el problema es que no tienes la teoría y quieres pasar a la práctica sin ella.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)